# Executing inserts using for loop into Sqlite3 not working

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, sqlite

I have 999 playlists in one file. Each has a list of songs. The file was flattened and converted to a pandas data frame. I need everything in a db, so I spun up a SQLite3 database like so.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('music.db')
cur = conn.cursor() 
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE entries (
name text,
collaborative text,
end_date text,
pid integer,
modified_at integer,
num_tracks integer,
num_albums integer,
num_edits integer,
num_artists integer,
description text,
pos integer,
artist_name text,
track_uri text,
artist_uri text,
track_name text,
album_uri text,
album_name text
)""")
```

I need to populate the table using data from the data frame. A for loop was assumed, and I consulted the docs for insertion syntax. I came up with the following code:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO entries VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17]])
```

I used print statements to check if row data were accessible using the indexes provided; they were. Then I ran the whole thing and got this gem of an error message:
`ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 17, and there are 9 supplied.`

I'm confident in my ability to count to 17. Does anyone see what's going wrong here?

Comment: Do you realize that `executemany` apply each element of the list you provided to the insertion statement? meaning that each of `row[1]` to `row[17]` should contain a tuple of 17 element, the passed list having 17 element is irrelevant.

Comment: @ahmad The database table contains 17 columns, just like the data dataframe that I am looping over. Every row is a dataframe row (there are ~ 69,000 rows), and the indexes correspond to the data I want in each column. Not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: `executemany` expects an iterator as a second argument, that iterator should yield a tuple with its count equal to the number of binding in the provided statement, `executemany` is roughly implemented as the following:

`def executemany(self, stmt, it): for item in it: self.execute(stmt, item)`

So my question was why are you using `executemany` and not `execute`?

Comment: @ahmad Well, I have many rows to insert. I just changed it to `.execute`.  I got a new error. `InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 9 - probably unsupported type.` Parameter 9 is an integer. It had better be supported.

Comment: This possibly could be a result of incorrect data, you need to find out at which row this error occurs, and check if this value at the 9th column is indeed an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, here you no need to create table directly convert your data into sql format -

import required

```
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

Establish connection, replace keywords as per your database name and all

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://" + "user_name" + ":" + "password" + "@" + "localhost" + "/" + "database_name")
```

Now covert your df to sql

```
df.to_sql('file_name_to_sql', con=engine, if_exists = 'append',index = False, chunksize = 1000)
```

check if done or not

```
engine.execute('select * from file_name_to_sql limit 5').fetchall()
```

Comment: All but the last line worked. It may be because I had a table already created in a mysql db.

Comment: this worked for me, you can see [here](https://github.com/abhikashyapr22/ineuron-class_task_/blob/main/FInal_fitbit_task.ipynb) answer no-2

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! After some minor adjustments, it worked for me too!

Answer (score 0):

As [ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12582072/ahmad) said, your issue is probably incorrect data. I suggest you print the row numbers, and then check the last row before the error (added below).

You can also check data types, and ignore a row if it has an incorrect type (added below).

Also, don't use a for loop for the SQL execution itself. It slows down performance when you execute multiple queries. Use a for loop to build the values part of your query, and then execute one [multirow `insert` query](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/#:%7E:text=SQLite%20INSERT%20%E2%80%93%20Inserting%20multiple%20rows%20into%20a%20table) (you may need to scroll down the page if your browser works differently than mine) with the data from the for loop:

```py
insertRows = []
rowcount = 0    #for debugging
for row in df.itertuples():
    rowcount += 1
    print(rowcount)
    vals = []
    for i in range(1, 18):
        if type(row[i]) != int:
            ignoreRow = True
            break
        vals.append(row[i])
    if not ignoreRow:
        insertRows.append(f"({', '.join(vals)})")

cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO entries VALUES {', '.join(insertRows)}")
```